# Remove duplicate records but keep the oldest record

Tags: sql, ms-access, duplicates, ms-access-2010

I'm using Microsoft Access and would like to use a SQL query to remove duplicate records. Where there is a duplicate record, I want to keep the oldest transaction ID (or the lower number). In this scenario, I want to remove John Smith's record with Customer ID "1283."

```
| CustID | TransID | FirstName | LastName | Date | Email |
|2523 | 0029 | John | Smith | 22/04/19| zz@gmail.com
|2523 | 1283 | John | Smith | 14/07/21 | zz@gmail.com
|3746 | 2306 | Harry | Potter | 29/01/22 | xx@gmail.com
```

Comment: Try using Common Table Expressions (CTE). check this [link](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/delete-duplicates-sql-server/)

Answer (score 0):

This works in your scenario, but if the customer changes their email you will have two records.

```sql
select customerID, min(TransactionID),  FirstName , LastName , min(Date) , Email 
from table
group by customerID, FirstName, LastName, Email
```

Comment: Complete. Thanks! I'm a newbie and still learning.